# how to get started for web apps in android?

Tags: android, mean-stack

I know Android development using java in eclipse. I have heard people developing apps using mean stacks and all. What are they and how to get started to make android app which are connected to servers and all. I know all the basics of android app development and little more. What else should i learn to to make dynamic apps connected to internet?

Comment: You can start learning Volley from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn how to connect the application to Internet, and how to communicate. If you have knowledge of web development, you can create Web Services, Web APIs to communicate the server.

There are lots of tutorials available on the Internet, just learn and try.

Comment: Could u please explain from where to start? I know basic how internet works , server side and client side

Comment: Yes i know java, C, C++, XML, HTML/CSS and a little PHP

Comment: If you are going to develop some application in Android then you need to know Core Java and Android. If you want to develop the APIs for dynamic application development then you have to learn `PHP` more.